# Pass variable from controller to notification in Laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am finding it hard to understand the examples from the docs to the scenario I am having. In my project I have an application form which filled up by the user then admin will update that form once the application is approved, canceled etc.

Now I want to notify the user that her/his application has been approved, canceled etc.

in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'status' => 'required'
    ]);
    $requestData = $request->all();

    $loanapplication = LoanApplication::findOrFail($id);

    $loanapplication->update([
        "status"        => $request->status,
        "admin_notes"   => $request->admin_notes,
        "date_approval" => $request->date_approved
    ]);    

    if($request->notifyBorrower = 'on') {

        $user_id = $loanapplication->user_id;
        $status = $request->status;
        $this->notify(new AdminResponseToApplication($user_id));   
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'LoanApplication updated!');
}
```

In my AdminResponseToApplication.php I like to achieve this

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class AdminResponseToApplication extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;  
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail','database'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line(.$user->nameHere. 'your application has been '.$statusHere.'.')
            ->action('check it out', url('/'))
            ->subject('Regarding with your loan application')
            ->line('This is system generated. Do not reply here.');
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $user->nameHere,
            'status' => $statusHere,
            'title' => .$user->nameHere. 'your application has been '.$statusHere.'.',
            'url' => '/'
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get user object and call function notify() on it. $this->notify() will not work because **$this** is not an instance of User class.

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
```

`$user` in the `$user->notify(new AdminResponseToApplication($data))` function is available in notification class as `$notifiable`.

You can get any value of that object using **$notifiable->name** etc.

**Remember**:

**AdminResponseToApplication** is a class and you can do anything with it that a php class can.

So you can pass as many variables as you want to **AdminResponseToApplication** class in constructor and do what you want.

```
$user->notify(new AdminResponseToApplication($data))
```

As shown above I am sending a **$data** object to the class which is available in the constructor.

In the class

```
class AdminResponseToApplication extends notification implements ShouldQueue{
    use Queueable;

    public $myData;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->myData = $data;  //now you have a $data copied to $this->myData which
        // you can call it using $this->myData in any function of this class.
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @Afraz. it has error, it said "Undefined variable: data". I am bit lost on this part  `$user->notify(new AdminResponseToApplication($data));` ,  I know this is just your example, but what does $data should have? because what I am trying to pass is to data from 2 different table, one is the user and the other one is status from status table.

Comment: Do not pass $user to constructor because `$user->notify()` is already passing it as `$notifiable`. Only send $status. Hope this will remove the error you facing.
`$user->notify(new NotificationClassName($status))`;

Comment: error is gone but its not firing the notification. currently I have now this on my update function of my controller, `$user->notify(new AdminResponseToApplication($statusName));` on AdminResponseToApplication.php i declared `public $myStatus;` and 'public function __construct($statusName) {$this->myStatus = $statusName; }'  in `public function toDatabase($notifiable)` i return `'title' => $notifiable->name.' your loan has been '.$statusName->name,`

Comment: The code looks ok to me. Make sure your notifications requirements are done.